# Perl Range command mismatching similar strings with one ending in a carriage return

Tags: regex, perl

The range command in Perl

```
RANGE
/^        identifier                              cust_pri/ .. /addr-type-none/
```

matches on strings with `cust_pri` and `cust_pri_sip` where a carriage return is immediately after the string `cust_pri` (and `cust_pri_sip`). I don't want a match on `cust_pri_sip` but only on `cust_pri`.

I tried putting in `\r\n` and both individually to no avail. Is there a string or metachar I can put into the end of perl range to help differentiate the two strings?

I need to look at data for both types of interfaces but on the first range command it is also collecting the data the second range command is also collecting (`cust_pri_sip`) causing my first script to error out. The second works find. I cannot change the input data and I need a way to differentiate the two.

This is a sub script of the main Perl program

```
WIDTH = 65

DIRECTORY = /home/myfiles/

MASTER Config Lines

        identifier                              cust_pri
        description                             *
        addr prefix                             0.0.0.0
        network interfaces                      M00|1:\d*
        tcp media profile
        monitoring filters
        node functionality
        default location string
        alt family realm
        addr-type-none


RANGE
/^        identifier                              cust_pri/ .. /addr-type-none/
#
```

There is another sub script that is similar to above

```
RANGE
/^        identifier                              cust_pri_sip/ .. /addr-type-none/
```

The first script also collects the data of both scripts because it matches.

Comment: I'm trying to follow the code and goals, enough to reformat them readably, but I'm failing to understand enough of what you're trying to ask to reformat it, let alone answer it. Can you try to format your question a bit better so that we can tell what is code, what is sample text, and what the question is?

Comment: Are you looking for `/^identifier cust_pri$/`?

Answer (score 1):

You can explicitly exclude _sip with `/^ identifier cust_pri(?!_sip)/` or you can say cust_pri has to be at the end of the line with nothing after it with `/^ identifier cust_pri$/`

Comment: Also, there's the word boundary `\b` that might be helpful.

Comment: The $ sign at the end of the range worked.  Thank you